# How to split the long html text into div's with a specfic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am having the dynamic HTML text from the database which is very long and I want to split HTML text into different divs with a fixed height, like pagging.

The HTML text is very long like example:

```html
<div id="content"><p></p><section style="width:100%;height:25px;"><div style="float:left;width:45%">A/G RATIO</div><div style="float:left;width:19%">2</div><div style="float:left;width:18%"></div><div style="float:left;width:18%">0.8 - 2</div></section><p></p><p></p><li style="font-size: 13px; margin-left: 6px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style-type: disc; background-color: transparent;" dir="ltr">
<ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;">
    <li style="font-size: 13px; margin-left: -24px; vertical-align: baseline; list-style-type: disc; background-color: transparent;" dir="ltr"><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">Not all foetal structural anomalies manifest or &nbsp;addressed on T2 U.S. Foetal &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;biometry &amp; Estimated Foetal Wt. subject to statistical variation &amp; morphometry to technical limits</span><span style="font-size: 13.3333px; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: Questrial; background-color: transparent;">.</span><span style="font-size: 13.3333px;">&nbsp;Level II U.S &amp; Fetal Echo. indicated at &nbsp;20 Wks + &nbsp;in pregnancies at risk for foetal malformations. End Of report ( Films -2)&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 15px; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; font-family: Questrial; background-color: transparent;">Thanks for the courtesy of referral.
    <div id="radePasteHelper" style="border: 0px solid red; border-image-source: none; left: -10000px; top: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; ;">
    Not all foetal structural anomalies manifest or &nbsp;addressed on T2 U.S. Foetal &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;biometry &amp; Estimated Foetal Wt. subject to statistical variation &amp; morphometry to technical limits
    .S &amp; Fetal Echo. indicated at &nbsp;20 Wks + &nbsp;in pregnancies at risk for foetal malformations.
    End Of report ( Films -2)Thanks for the courtesy of referral.
    </div>
    </span></li>
</ul>
</li><p></p><p><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"></font><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Obstetrical Ultrasound Exam. Twin Gestation (Level I)</font><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></p><ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 19px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><h1 dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-weight: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Bichorionic, biamniotic, concordant live intrauterine twin pregnancies noted in lie: longitudinal cephalic ( Fetus A) &amp; podolic ( Fetus B). </font></h1></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: -18px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Foetal cardiac activity &amp; body movements normally present. FHRs: &nbsp;&amp; 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;BPM . </font></li></ul><ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Individual Foetal parameters as on scans &amp; correspond to mean gestational age </font></li></ul><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wks &nbsp;&nbsp;Ds &nbsp;&amp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Wks &amp; &nbsp;&nbsp;Ds with &nbsp;mean derived LMP: &nbsp;&nbsp;&amp; EDD: &nbsp;</font><ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">No gross ultrasonologically detectable cranio-spinal or abdominal &nbsp;anomaly noted at this stage in both the foetii.*</font></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Placenta fused: Position: &nbsp;Anterior Grade B &nbsp;with no low extension.</font></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Liquor quantity appears &nbsp;&nbsp;adequate in both the sacs.</font></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Cervical length is: </font><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">. &nbsp;(Normal 3.0 cms +).</font></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: 6px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">No gross adnexeal pathology demonstrated.</font></li></ul><br><p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; margin-left: 90pt; text-indent: -90pt;"><br></p><font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Impression : Biamniotic, Bichorionic Concordant Twin IU Live Pregnancies of approx. &nbsp;Wk &amp; &nbsp;&nbsp;Ds (</font><font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">+</font><font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"> 2Wk). Estimated Ft.Wts. &nbsp;1 &nbsp;&amp; 1 &nbsp;gms ( </font><font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">+</font><font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"> 15 %).</font>&nbsp;<font face="Questrial" size="3" style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Disparity from KLMP: &nbsp;&nbsp;Ds larger &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><br></p><ul style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: -24px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Not all foetal structural anomalies manifest or &nbsp;addressed on T2 U.S. Foetal &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;biometry &amp; Estimated Foetal Wt. subject to statistical variation &amp; morphometry to technical limits</font><font face="Questrial" style="background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.</font></li><li dir="ltr" style="list-style-type: disc; font-size: 13px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; margin-left: -24px;"><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Level II U</font><font face="Questrial" style="background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">.S &amp; Fetal Echo. indicated at &nbsp;20 Wks + &nbsp;in pregnancies at risk for foetal malformations.</font></li></ul><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">End Of report ( Films -2)</font>&nbsp;<font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">Thanks for the courtesy of referral.</font><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><div><font face="Questrial" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">&nbsp;</font></div><br><br><br><br><p></p><p></p>
        </div>
    </div
```

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: As far as I understood the question, I suggest you can store entire HTML structured text in the database so that when you retrieve the value from DB you get what you want instead of processing it at client side.

Comment: i have stored in the database itself but i want to print the HTML structured text with header and footer fix and the content is 400px height .

Comment: I am having Dynamic content which is coming from database with the formatting text(like inline- css) and i want to split this content into multiple div's with specific heights. so that i can print this data into A4 pages with header and footer Fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the entire html in a hidden `div` or other element in the dom, say with id container and then use `children().each()` to loop over all first level divs and apply any css or other tricks to them.

```
var pagearray = []
$('#container').children('div').each(function () {
     //'this' is a div object which you can use
     pagearray.push( $(this).html() );
});
//show first page
$("#page").html(pagearray[0]);
```

Comment: The Complete Html is in Single Div and which is dynamic and i don't know where to mark to split the text.it should divide according to the height  base like 400px div. According to the div height it should fix few lines and the remaining should be shifted to another div or page

Comment: Aaah ok that is not clear in your question..

Comment: i am having Dynamic content which is coming from database with the formatting text(like inline- css) and i want to split this content into multiple div's with specific heights. so that i  can print this data into A4 pages with header and footer Fix.